# why obj={x,y} works in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var obj = { type: 'data', x, y, data: []}
```

Obviously this was my typo, `{x,y}` should have been {x:x, y:y}. But it does what I want, in Chrome, field `x` gets the value of a local variable `x`.

But why does it work?

Comment: Version 43.0.2357.81 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is part of the ECMAScript 2015 (or ECMAScript 6). You can create new properties in Objects in Object literals, just by specifying the identifiers.

Quoting [MDN's Object Initializer's Property Definitions section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions),

> With ECMAScript 6, there is a shorter notation available to achieve the same:
>
> ```
> var a = "foo", 
>     b = 42, 
>     c = {};
>
> // Shorthand property names (ES6)
> var o = { a, b, c };
> ```

---

The corresponding section in ECMAScript 6 specification is [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation),

> *AssignmentProperty* : *IdentifierReference* *Initializer<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> 1. Let *P* be StringValue of *IdentifierReference*.
> 2. Let *lref* be ResolveBinding(*P*).
> 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(*P*).
> 4. Let *v* be GetV(*value*, *P*).
> 5. ReturnIfAbrupt(*v*).
> 6. If *Initializer<sub>opt</sub>* is present and *v* is **undefined**, then
>
>    1. Let *defaultValue* be the result of evaluating *Initializer*.
>    2. Let *v* be GetValue(*defaultValue*).
>    3. ReturnIfAbrupt(*v*).
>    4. If IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition(*Initializer*) is **true**, then
>
>       1. Let *hasNameProperty* be HasOwnProperty(*v*, "name").
>       2. ReturnIfAbrupt(*hasNameProperty*).
>       3. If *hasNameProperty* is **false**, perform SetFunctionName(*v*, *P*).
> 7. Return PutValue(*lref*,*v*).

Basically, the specification says that, if you are using just an identifier, a new property with the name of the identifier will be created, and the value will be the actual value of that identifier. It can even be a name of the function.

```
var a = "foo", b = 42, c = {}, d = function () {};    
console.log({a, b, c, d});
// { a: 'foo', b: 42, c: {}, d: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 5):

ES2015 has enhanced object literal notation. [Chrome 43ish](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions) supports this (partially).

[Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) has a good explanation.